# Site for APP IOS AND ANDROID

Tags: java, android, ios, ionic-framework

Good afternoon ,
I currently have a simple website made in Wordpress and would like to create a webview to encapsulate the same.

The goal is to look like an App, so that the client can download for both Android and IOS, install and in fact he will see the mobile version of the site.

I know how to make an App from scratch but I can not pass the site codes to it.

Can someone help me?
I searched so much on the internet but found nothing.

Comment: "make android or ios app from website" would be a good web search start. Unfortunately, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. The answer is "research some tools that can turn a web site into a platform specific or cross-platform app and try them." It isn't appropriate to recommend any tools or APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to show the website in a web view, you can do that. For Android, you'll load the URL into a WebView. For iOS, you can use SFSafariViewController.

Official documentation:

WebView: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

SFSafariViewController: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller

Edit: You probably won't actually be able to publish that, though. Maybe on Android, but on iOS, they want your app to be more than a repackaged website. See section 4.2 of the App Store review guidelines. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

I would perhaps recommend instructing your client how to add your website as a shortcut to the home screen of their phone.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Wordpress plugin to make your site a PWA
https://wordpress.org/plugins/pwa/